# How is this Eratosthenes Sieve implementation is working internally?

Tags: java, java-stream, primes, sieve, intstream

I found this code that seems to be the non-optimal version of the Sieve of Erastothenes, it gets the N first prime numbers into an array.

```
private IntPredicate p = x -> true;

private int[] primes(int n) {
    
    return IntStream.iterate(2, i -> i + 1)
        .filter(x -> p.test(x))
        .peek(i -> p = p.and(k -> k % i != 0))
        .limit(n)
        .toArray();
}
```

What's happening internally with the `IntPredicate`?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko actually if I just put a true literal in the filter method or just delete the filter method at all, I get a different input, may be I should add the output result.

Comment: I didn't see that the predicate is being altered by `peek()` because of the formating.

Comment: obligatory notice that this is *not* the sieve of Eratosthenes, but rather the non-optimal version of the sieve of trial division by primes.

Comment: @WillNess how would it be the optimal version of the sieve of Erastothenes? I couldn't find an implementation in Java.

Comment: optimal trial division test-divides each number by all the primes not exceeding the number's square root. your version test-divides each number by all the primes smaller than the number itself (which is, all the primes discovered thus far in the iteration). see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=postponed%20user%3a849891). and again, these are _not_ sieves of _Eratosthenes_, which does _not_ test-divide numbers at all but instead counts up from a discovered prime in steps of that prime and _thus_ discovers that prime's multiples: (contd.)

Comment: ... ``primes = [2,3,...] `set-minus` [[2p,3p,...] FOR p IN primes]``.

Comment: @Brando Jeanpier you can find a Java implementation of the Sieve of Eratosthenes in the middle of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48754107/making-a-parallel-intstream-more-efficient-faster/48764124#48764124:~:text=Sieve%20of%20Eratosthenes)

Comment: @Holger thank you so much, I need to try it.

Answer (score 4):

This code produces an aggregate Predicate via [`IntPredicate.and()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/IntPredicate.html) method, which would work this way:

```
p = x -> true; // for first stream element `2` - 
               //   which passes the predicate p

// Predicate p is being reassigned while
// peek() sees the element `2`, to
p = x -> true && x % 2 != 0

// The next stream element `3` passes the updated predicate
// And the predicate is being reassigned again while
// peek() sees the element `3` to

p = x -> true && x % 2 != 0 && x % 3 != 0

// And so on...
```

So every element which successfully passes the `filter` results in a new condition being appended to the current predicate via "logical AND" `&&`.

At the end of the stream execution, the predicate would consist of conditions that check the given number against all the prime number from that would be present in the result.

**Note** that this hacky implementation is broken:

[`peek()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#peek(java.util.function.IntConsumer)) is an operation which was introduced exclusively to support debugging. It's not meant to be used for performing actions that could affect the result of the execution. `peek` gives no guaranty regarding the order in which it will be called while executing in parallel, and in certain cases can be optimized away.